# Running android emulator from vs code gradle error

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle, android-emulator, gradle-task

I am new to flutter and coding in general. I am trying to run an android emulator from vs code but I keep getting the below error when trying to do so. Could you point me in the right direction of how I fix this.

Error

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
'Dart\Rivan_Flutter_Course\currency_converter\android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I had a & symbol in my folder structure and that was the issue